# Excel: Combination of "top 10" and "bottom 10" conditional formatting. Possible?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a set of data that I want to set conditional formatting on. The problem with a straight top 10 / bottom 10 conditional formatting is that some of the states in the top 10 "AVG response Hours" might also be in the top 10 "AVG Incident total", which is not what I want.

What I want is when any of the values of "AVG Response Hours" fall in the top 10% AND when the values of "Avg Incident total" of that state also falls in TOP 10 (NOT bottom 10), then conditional format both the "Avg Incident total" value and the "AVG Response Hours" values for that state.

Does that make sense? Here is a sample data example:

[image: Example]

I really appreciate the help!

Comment: What cells are you wanting to highlight?

Comment: Both the column circled in red and the "Avg Incident total" column.

Comment: Are you looking to do it by date. Or the top ten of all the dates?

Comment: Top 10 of all Dates. 

So I realized my post was not accurate. What im trying to accomplish is when any of the values of "AVG Response Hours" fall in the top 10% AND when the values of "Avg Incident total" of that state also falls in TOP 10 (NOT bottom 10), then conditional format both the "Avg Incident total" value and the "AVG Response Hours" values for that state. 

I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Bump? Anyone? Much appreciated